# How to render an HTML page with JSON data in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I've been trying to build an anime app by getting data from an API Wrapper (api.jikan.moe). I've made a form in an HTML form to send post data, then my node.js script gets the data from the API.

How do I render the JSON and display the json data in the form of an HTML page?

Here's my code
**index.html**

```
<form  method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/find">
        <div class="form">
                <input type="text" name="animeName" placeholder="Anime Name"><input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchBtn">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**main.js**

```
app.post('/find', (req, res) => {
mal.search('anime', req.body.animeName, '')
    .then(info => {
        let list = []
        for(var i = 0; i < info.results.length; i++){
            list.push(info['results'][i])
        }
        res.json(info)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.send("Error Occured")
    })
})
```

Comment: If you want Express to send HTML then send HTML and not JSON.

Comment: how exactly? can you post some code?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score -1):

When you submit the form, the form data is sent to the server and the page is refreshed.

You will have to use AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: "the page is refreshed" — no, the JSON is displayed

Comment: "You will have to use AJAX to submit the form" — No, a regular form submission is fine.

Comment: Quentin, I'm having some trouble using template engines, could you write some boilerplate code as to how it may work?

Comment: Why did you downvote?

You can do this using AJAX as follows
`$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/find",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#animeForm").append(JSON.stringify(data));`